# MYSQL Select and Update with same where clause different row counts

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Server version: 10.1.30-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

When I run this select query I get 157 rows returned:

```
SELECT * FROM `ii_Product`
    WHERE `number` LIKE 'FUN%' AND `supplierId` = '220'
```

When I run an update that should change the same rows it only updates 7 rows.

```
UPDATE `ii_Product`
    SET `notes`= concat ('Former ABC item. DOUBLE CHECK AVAILABILITY.\n',`notes`)
    WHERE `number` LIKE 'FUN%' AND `supplierId` = '220'
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Perhaps some notes are already updated

Comment: @Strawberry - That's what I thought, too.  But note that `notes` necessarily gets longer by the operation.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE ii_product` and `SELECT MAX(LENGTH(notes)) FROM ii_product;`

Comment: @RickJames 2 weeks on, and no appearance from the OP, I've moved on.

Comment: `notes` is a text field with no max length. `MAX(LENGTH(notes))  
= 65535`